# Ember.js : How to find records that do NOT have a property set?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a bunch of Records that "belongsTo" other records. (Different models, just typical 1-n relationship.) How can I call find on my model to find all those that have NO belongs-to association?

Something like:

```
App.Thing = DS.Model.extend({
 other: DS.belongsTo( 'App.Other' ),
 someattr: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Thing.find({ other: null });
```

**EDIT:**

louiscoquio's solution didn't work for me. So I thought I could filter in the controller.

Here's how I try to do it:

```
App.ThingsAsideController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  unassigned: function() {
   return this.filterProperty('other');
  }.property('content.@each')
});
```

This works just fine if I filter for `someattr` but I cannot filter for the relationship.

I guess the question is: What is the property name for the belongsTo association?

**EDIT**, SOMETHING THAT WORKS:

This works, but I'm very unhappy with it:

```
 App.ThingsAsideController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   unassigned: function() {
     return this.filter(function(item, index, enumerable){

       var belongsToOther = false;

       var otherThings = App.OtherThing.find();
       otherThings.forEach( function( otherThing ){
         otherThing.get('things').forEach( function( otherThingThing ) {
            if( otherThingThing.id === item.id ) {
              belongsToOther = true;
            }
         });
       });

       return !belongsToOther;
    });
```

I've been reading ember-data source but I can't find out how to query the belongs-to association of a record.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`filter`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L821-L863) method available to `DS.Model` classes:

```
var filteredThings = App.Thing.filter(function(thing) {
  return thing.get('other') === null;
});
```

It returns an array that contains all `App.Thing` which returned `true` in the callback you pass.

As the documentation says:

> It returns a live RecordArray that remains up to date as new records are loaded into the store or created
>       locally.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like return thing.other === null; in this case?